# Root of quadratic polynomial with Python

Tags: python

I know this is asking me to use if statements. But how can I go about doing this?

Write a program qroots.py that reads three floats a, b, c from the command line and computes/prints the roots of the quadratic polynomial `ax**2 + bx + c = 0`. Your program needs to handle only the case when real roots exist, i.e., when the values of a, b, c produce a non-negative discriminant `b**2 − 4ac >= 0`.

When the discriminant is negative your program should only print a message that no real roots exist.

Hint: math.sqrt() is the built-in function that returns the square root of a number.

I have this so far:

```
import sys
import math

a = float(sys.argv[1])
b = float(sys.argv[2])
c = float(sys.argv[3])
```

Terminal should do this:

> qroots.py 1 -3 2
>
> 1.0 2.0

Comment: please read how to ask in SO. this is not a site to solve homework. show what you have done

Comment: hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you read up on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) prior to asking this question?

Comment: @YanetPedraza not homework, online learning, I will edit now

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Check the value of the discriminant in [an if statement](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html).  In the `if`, do one thing, in the `else`, do the other.

Comment: Friend @Jama, show us what you have done and we will be pleased to help you.

Comment: You don't know how to approach this, so here's an idea: There's three subproblems: 1) read the parameters from command line (google that). 2) check if root exists. 3) if yes, print the roots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read the input from the command line (hint : use `sys.argv`). Also you will need to figure out how to convert strings to python numbers.

Then check if `b**2-4*a*c < 0`. If yes, then raise a `ValueError` about that there are no real roots.

Else solve for the roots: `roots = (b ± sqrt(b**2-4*a*c)) / (2*a)`

Answer (score 0):

Procedure as decribed in my comment and in @Joran Beasley's answer:

```
import sys
from math import sqrt

a, b, c = sys.argv[1:]
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
c = float(c)
if b**2-4*a*c < 0:
    print("there's no real root")
else:
    print((-b+sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/(2*a), (-b-sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/(2*a))
```

If you like, you can also check if the discriminant is zero and only print one of the two solutions (which are obviously equal in this case).